# Eclipse - Compile all files in directory

Tags: eclipse

I have a team project that has a directory of files that change all the time (files are added, removed, and renamed by an auto-coder). It is a pain to frequently remove the old files from Eclipse and then add the new ones.

In a Makefile you can tell it to compile all the files in a directory like this:

```
$(wildcard path/*.cpp)
```

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to compile all files of a certain type in a directory? Or at least all files in a directory?

Answer (score 0):

I hear you asking, how can I configure a system to compile files that appear in a directory on an irregular basis.  Is that right?  And you didn't specify what language; based on mention of make with a cpp rule I'm guessing either C/C++, but just might be Java.

Anyhow, I wouldn't recommend Eclipse for this task. Instead you might look into build & continuous integration systems such as Jenkins http://jenkins-ci.org

Comment: Your first statement is correct with the exception that "system" must mean Eclipse. Unfortunately, Eclipse is a requirement that I must use due to the constraints given to me.